# Controller.set in IndexRoute

Tags: ember.js

I have following js code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts');
    this.resource('about');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     setupController: function(controller) {
         controller.set('title', "test");
     }
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('title', 'test');
    }
});
```

And following html page:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>{{#linkTo index}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
                    <li>{{#linkTo posts}}Posts{{/linkTo}}</li>
                    <li>{{#linkTo about}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{title}} // <--- no title here
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
    About template
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1> // <--- works here
    Recent posts
</script>
```

I got rendered {{title}} variable only at posts route. It doesn't work at index route though. I was reading manual and tried to do exactly as is mentioned there: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think you'd have to set that in the `ApplicationRoute`

Comment: Well, if I use ApplicationRoute I get {{title}} rendered everywhere but it seems a little bit confusing, because if I put console.log('test') in setupController function and navigate through my navbar I get the message only once if I use ApplicationRoute and each time when I go to '/' if I use IndexRoute. Okay, keep on struggling with EmberJs! Thank you!